# Connect button to a function in PyQt5 not working

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to make

```
confirminformation_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.abss)
```

work.

my main.py, the controller:

```
import sys, pdb
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        main_ui.show()
        self.setSignals()
    def setSignals(self):
        main_ui.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.openConfirmation)
    def openConfirmation(self):

        Confirmation()
    def closeWindow(self):
        self.close()

class Confirmation():
    def __init__(self):
        main_ui.close()
        confirminformation_ui.show()
        self.setSignals()
    def setSignals(self):
        confirminformation_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.abss)
    def abss(self):
        print("lineofabss")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_ui = uic.loadUi('main_window.ui')
    confirminformation_ui = uic.loadUi('confirm_information.ui')
    appointments_ui = uic.loadUi('appointment_list.ui')

    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

my pushButton not work with self.abss. But works with any global function. For example:

```
import sys, pdb
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

def debug():
    print("works")

class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        main_ui.show()
        self.setSignals()
    def setSignals(self):
        main_ui.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.openConfirmation)
    def openConfirmation(self):

        Confirmation()
    def closeWindow(self):
        self.close()

class Confirmation():
    def __init__(self):
        main_ui.close()
        confirminformation_ui.show()
        self.setSignals()
    def setSignals(self):
        confirminformation_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(debug)
    def abss(self):
        print("lineofabss")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_ui = uic.loadUi('main_window.ui')
    confirminformation_ui = uic.loadUi('confirm_information.ui')
    appointments_ui = uic.loadUi('appointment_list.ui')

    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

output: works
```

I only defined a global funcion debug() and i connected it to pushButton, and it worked.
Why do the self.abss not work?

confirminformation_ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>503</width>
    <height>412</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Indian Mission Name</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox"/>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Application ID (Filenumber)</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Date of birth</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QCalendarWidget" name="calendarWidget">
     <property name="locale">
      <locale language="Hindi" country="India"/>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Submit</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

appointmentlist_ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>314</width>
    <height>471</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="1" column="0">
    <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget"/>
   </item>
   <item row="5" column="0">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Confirm the appointment</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Appointments:</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="4" column="0">
    <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox"/>
   </item>
   <item row="3" column="0">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Select Date:</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="0">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
     <property name="text">
      <string>About</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="1">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Logout</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

main_window.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>423</width>
    <height>366</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Filenumber</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="filenumber_lineedit"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Passport No</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="passport_lineedit"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
      <property name="text">
       <string>OTP</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="otp_lineedit"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="generate_otp_btn">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Generate OTP</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>40</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="login_btn">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Login</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Not sure about this (without main_window.ui, confirm_information.ui and appointment_list.ui, I can't run your code and test it).  But it looks like in `openConfirmation()`, you are calling `Confirmation()` to create an object of the Confirmation class.  But you aren't keeping any reference to it, so I wonder if it isn't the case that by the time you click pushButton, the Confirmation object doesn't exist anymore, and there is no self.abss.  In the line where you call `Confirmation()`, try assigning it to something (e.g., a property of the MainWindow() object).

Comment: It make sense jfsturtz. I don't have idea what can be done in this case. Besides, i added those ui files

Comment: in the Confirmation() line i tried to link the assigning the button to the function, but it still don't work.

i did
        def openConfirmation(self):

                conf = Confirmation()
                confirminformation_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(conf.abss)

Comment: It doesn't help if you assign it to a local variable.  That also goes out of scope at the same time the Confirmation() object does.  Try this:  `self.conf = Confirmation()' [i.e., you are assigning the created Confirmation() object to a property of the MainWindow() object, which will not go out of scope, and stick around].  I made that change to your code, and that seems to work for me (at least, I see the message "lineofabss" ...)

Comment: i didn't remember this trick. thanks jfsturtz

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the fine details, but it has to do with the object `self` being passed along as a parameter of your method in the function call.

You have to replace the call to your method:

```
confirminformation_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.abss)
```

with a lambda function:

```
confirminformation_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.abss())
```

Comment: I was running into the same issue, and I can confirm that using the lambda function works.